Cross-posting a challenge
I have posted this question on the Puzzling SE site: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/101905/71326. However, it did not generate much interest. I could offer a bounty, but I wonder if I would have better luck re-posting on the Cryptography site. I understand cross-posting should be avoided, so I'm hesitant. Also, I'm not sure "can you help crack this cipher?" is an appropriate type of question for the Cryptography site. What do you think? Would this post do better on the Cryptography site? Would it be appropriate? If not, do you have any advice on how to get help on solving this?

If you really want an answer you can set a bounty on it.


Also, I'm not sure "can you help crack this cipher?" is an appropriate type of question for the Cryptography site.

You've answered your own question. From the Help Center:

Can I get data analysed here? Can I challenge people to decode something?
No. Such questions are not considered helpful.

It's also one of the community-specific reasons to close a question:

Puzzling Stack Exchange is the right site for that puzzle.

Ah! I should have RTFM better. Thanks for pointing that out to me.
